# Depth interpolation for surface removal with perspective projection

Tags: math, 3d, interpolation, perspective

This seems like a question for which an answer should readily available on the web or books but my quest for an answer has led me so far only to blind alleys that turned out to be dead ends.

I'm trying to draw 3D lines in real-time with hidden surface removal (the lines are edges of solid objects).

So I have two 3D points that were projected to 2D points using perspective projection. For each point I have computed the depth of the point. Now I want to draw the line segment that joins the 2 points, and for hidden surface removal to work I have to compute, for each intermediary 2D point on the 2D line (that results from the projection) the depth of the corresponding 3D point (the 3D point that is projected on that intermediary 2D point).

My problem is that, since the depth function isn't linear when you do perspective projection, I can't interpolate the depth of the 2 original 3D points to compute the depth of the intermediary point.

So how do I compute the depth of each point on the line with a method that's compatible with the constraints of real-time rendering?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding Projection and z distance.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805992/finding-projection-and-z-distance)

Comment: the answer is readily available - it was asked here just 5 hours ago...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use homogeneous coordinates, which can be linearly interpolated in screen space: http://www.cs.unc.edu/~olano/papers/2dh-tri/

Comment: still not getting it: the only definition of depth that I know is the square root of the sum of the square of the coordinates if the center or projection is at the origin. Given that definition I don't see how this Depth function (or its inverse 1/Depth) could be linear and therefore interpolable

Comment: That's distance from the origin.  Depth in computer graphics terminology is Z.  1/Z is linearly interpolatable.

Comment: Ok, but to do hidden surface removal (when using perspective projection), isn't distance from the center of projection what's needed? Distance from the center of projection is what I use when I do hidden surface removal in the context of ray tracing and it works fine. Is 1/Z an approximation that's good enough for for most cases?

Comment: No, 1/Z is exact for rasterization.  (See http://chrishecker.com/images/4/41/Gdmtex1.pdf).  In a perspective projection, ordering pixels by Z (or -1/Z) is sufficient.  Try drawing a view frustum, and drawing rays from the eye out into space.  As long as the view angle is less than 180 degrees, Z provides a correct ordering along any ray.  Now, if you wanted to compare distance between different rays (i.e., different pixels), you'd need to take into account X and Y, too.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to this great article from Chris Hecker. It is very informative although it doesn't contain a proof that using Z (as opposed to the actual distance from center of projection) for hidden surface removal is sufficient as I thought you implied at first. Although it intuitively makes sense I wish I had a mathematical proof of that.

Comment: I think all you have to show is that for a fixed screen X,Y (after projection), there is a monotonic relationship between -1/Z and the function for actual distance.  I don't think this is too hard to show.